# Is there any way I can make my Fyne application in go run by just following the steps in windows 10 because is throwing gcc executable not found

Tags: go, gcc, windows-10, fyne

I am trying to build GUI application using Go Fyne Framework, I followed the guidelines that the docs provide, but I am missing something what it seems like is gcc but that doesn't have to be a problem bc I have downloaded and installed the msys2 mingx64 I am confused please help the error is below.

```
# github.com/go-gl/glfw/v3.3/glfw
cgo: C compiler "gcc" not found: exec: "gcc": executable file not found in %PATH%
# github.com/go-gl/gl/v3.2-core/gl
cgo: C compiler "gcc" not found: exec: "gcc": executable file not found in %PATH%
PS C:\Users\weske\OneDrive\Desktop\FyneGems> go build .\main.go
# github.com/go-gl/glfw/v3.3/glfw
cgo: C compiler "gcc" not found: exec: "gcc": executable file not found in %PATH%
# github.com/go-gl/gl/v3.2-core/gl
cgo: C compiler "gcc" not found: exec: "gcc": executable file not found in %PATH%
PS C:\Users\weske\OneDrive\Desktop\FyneGems> go build
# github.com/go-gl/glfw/v3.3/glfw
cgo: C compiler "gcc" not found: exec: "gcc": executable file not found in %PATH%
# github.com/go-gl/gl/v3.2-core/gl
cgo: C compiler "gcc" not found: exec: "gcc": executable file not found in %PATH%
```

Comment: Did you follow the steps at https://developer.fyne.io/started/?

Answer (score 0):

Mingw64 does not install gcc unless you ask it to. There are steps for the unsure at https://developer.fyne.io/started/